# Custom UITableView Cell Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've been following a guide to create my own UITableView cell and I created the class and the interface successfully.

When I tried to change my app code from the default `UITableViewCell`
to my custom-made `SimpleTableCell` I got the following error:
[My code and the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMuIN.png)

Why I get this error while the commented area in the above code works great?

The error appears in the following line:

```
SimpleTableCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
```

Comment: Don't post images. Post the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that at the top of your file you have

```
#import "SimpleTableCell.h"
```

or whichever other header in which this class is declared.

Comment: Lol, I really forgot importing it. Thank!